# MySQL IS NULL not working

Tags: mysql, sql, null, isnull

Have some ( difficult ) MySQL query

```
SELECT
    *,
    (
        SELECT
             MIN(tbl.id)
        FROM
           stat tbl 
        WHERE   
            tbl.id > stat.id
            and tbl.user_id=stat.user_id
    ) next_session_id,  
    (
        Select
            (case
                when next_session_id IS NULL then '9999-12-31 23:59:59' else sub.date
            end)
        from
            stat sub
        where 
            sub.id=next_session_id
    ) next_date
FROM
    stat    
WHERE       
    user_id=15973
    and date >'2014-06-01'
```

Problem in next, for last row `next_session_id` are `NULL`(check in MySQL Workbench) and it must return datetime `'9999-12-31 23:59:59'`, but return `NULL`. Check `IS NULL` not work i think or incorrect. Why it's happen?
**UPDATE**
Example of result set
[image]

Comment: Can you provide sample table data and what output you are getting with this query?

Comment: As @Griddor said: your `WHERE` clause in the `SELECT` for your computed next_date will not be true, if `next_session_id IS NULL`. You could rewrite this to `WHERE sub.id = next_session_id OR next_session_id IS NULL`.

Comment: @VMai thx for explanation. I make some modify in my query + your explanation and all fine. Add your comment like answer and I choose gratefully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `OR next_session_id IS NULL` to the `WHERE` clause of your subselect

```
SELECT
    (CASE
        WHEN next_session_id IS NULL THEN '9999-12-31 23:59:59' ELSE sub.date
    END)
FROM
    stat sub
WHERE 
    sub.id=next_session_id OR next_session_id IS NULL
```

because without that the where condition will not be true, if next_session is null.

Answer (score 1):

In database NULL and `''` (empty string) are different. So ensure you have `NULL` value instead of `''` (empty string) in your table.

Check this query with your table
`SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE next_session_id=''`

Comment: I know this moment. And I say that check value in workbench! Table doesn't have this column. It create with help subquery

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this part

```
Select
    (case
        when next_session_id IS NULL then '9999-12-31 23:59:59' else sub.date
    end)
from
    stat sub
where 
    sub.id=next_session_id
```

to

```
    case
        when next_session_id IS NULL then '9999-12-31 23:59:59' else (
            Select sub.date
            from
            stat sub
            where 
            sub.id=next_session_id)
    end
```

Because in MySQL, NULL = NULL doesn't evaluate to true.

Comment: NULL IS NULL return 1 but NULL=NULL return NULL. IS NULL was create for that moments

Comment: And your variant create same result.

Comment: @disable1992 Why? Doesn't it yield the literal when next_session_id is NULL?

Answer (score 0):

I think `IS NULL` is not working because of some reason, so you can use `= ''`,
for example `x is null` you can use `x = ''` instead.